# Matlab installation error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-14.04

My input file is

```
mode=silent
agreeToLicense=yes
destinationFolder=/opt/mcr
fileInstallationKey=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
lmgrFiles=false
lmgrService=false
licensePath=/path/to/license
product.MATLAB
```

I run command like this

```
$ ./install -inputFile my_input.txt
```

And this error appears

```
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) Starting local product/component search in download directory
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) Searching for archives...
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) Reading /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a/archives
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) 12 files found in /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a/archives
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) Reading /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) 16 files found in /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) Reading /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a/archives
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) 12 files found in /root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2015a/archives
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) Archive search complete.  40 total files found.
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:19) Assembling product list...
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:20) Completed local product/component search
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:20) Error: Unable to locate required installation files.
Using a File Installation Key requires you run the installer from a MATLAB DVD or from a directory which contains files previously downloaded via the installer.
To obtain the missing files,  click Back on the previous screen and select Log in with a MathWorks Account or contact your MATLAB license administrator.
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:20) Exiting with status -2
(Jun 23, 2015 06:23:21) End - Unsuccessful.
```

I try to search but don't know how to catch this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install matlab-gdf dynare-matlab libpdl-io-matlab-perl matlab-support matlab-support-dev matlab2tikz`

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh I tried that. `E: Unable to locate package matlab-gdf`
`E: Package 'dynare-matlab' has no installation candidate`
`E: Package 'matlab-support' has no installation candidate` And my above error appears same.

Comment: I have to install through this link refer it may be its helpful to u >>  http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-and-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh Thanks I will try. One more question. You installed with GUi?

Comment: Yes but not in 14.04 ---> into 12.04

Answer (score -1):

You can just install with this one line of command.

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-gdf dynare-matlab libpdl-io-matlab-perl matlab-support matlab-support-dev matlab2tikz
```